# Why is my input slider not showing the actual slider in a node group?

Tags: materials, node-editor

See this image:

[image: Slider Woes]

I would like to have a slider for the "Less/More" value. Its range is from -1 to 1. The value itself updates, but Blender doesn't want to draw the actual blue slider.

What's the issue here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please [edit] your question and add an image of the contents of the node group.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. You have to create the input from a slider value in the first place. Here's an example gif:

[image: Slider in Node Group]

You can't go back and change it after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

Blender simply does not draw any slider for the input values of node group
But you can have a minimum value and maximum value of any value easily set up by the pressing N in node editor
It will not be drawn as slider but it will not go less than minimum value and more than maximum value

If you want to have a slider,you may need to use any additional add-on
I don't know about any such add-on till now

Comment: Check my answer below, you can do it.

Comment: Sorry but this will not work for him because he needs the minimum and maximum value of -1 and 1... This sider just goes from 0 to 1

Comment: He can use map range node to make it work...

Comment: There is no need for a map range node, it works fine as I outlined in my answer. The slider works from -1 to +1.

Comment: Hello, this answer and your comments are not true. You can both use a slider in a node group by first linking the input to a slider field (fe the factor of a mix rgb node) and then remap it to your desired values in the node group properties in the N panel